# Firebase Authentication with Google and Facebook account with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to integrate Firebase Authentication API with my React app and everything is working properly for email/password registration and login. However, I'm facing an issue with Facebook and Google Authentication. Whenever I try to connect, I get the following error

> auth/invalid-continue-uri Firebase: The continue URL provided in the request is invalid. (auth/invalid-continue-uri)

Localhost is added to the authorized domains in firebase and Google and Facebook providers are enabled.

Here is the code of the component:

```
const googleLogin = async () => {
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("here");
      // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      const token = credential.accessToken;
      // The signed-in user info.
      const user = result.user;
      // IdP data available using getAdditionalUserInfo(result)
      // ...
      console.log(token, user);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
      // The email of the user's account used.
      const email = error.customData.email;
      // The AuthCredential type that was used.
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
      // ...
    });
};

const facebookLogin = async () => {
  const provider = new FacebookAuthProvider();
  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
      // The signed-in user info.
      const user = result.user;

      // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
      const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      const accessToken = credential.accessToken;

      // IdP data available using getAdditionalUserInfo(result)
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorMessage);
      // The email of the user's account used.
      const email = error.customData.email;
      // The AuthCredential type that was used.
      const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);

      // ...
    });
};
```

Can someone please help me to fix this issue?